# Different angle in inspector and in code - unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem understanding rotation in unity. Why is the rotation in the inspector not the same as the rotation in the code. And why Y and Z is 180*?

Debug code in Update

```
Debug.Log(transform.rotation.eulerAngles);

// Same thing with rigidbody
Debug.Log(_rigidbody.rotation.eulerAngles);
```

Inspector:

[image]

Object in hierarchy

[image]

Comment: [`eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html)!

Answer (score 0):

in the inspector the local euler angles are showed, in your code it's absolute euler angle.

use localEuler angle instead if you want to get same result with inspector.

Comment: Same values....

Comment: @cyberfrogg can you provide the hierarchy and highlight the game object which you run the script

Comment: hierarchy updated

Comment: @cyberfrogg same with a demo project. please have a look of this [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localEulerAngles.html) When you read the .eulerAngles property, Unity converts the Quaternion's internal representation of the rotation to Euler angles. Because, there is more than one way to represent any given rotation using Euler angles, the values you read back out may be quite different from the values you assigned. This can cause confusion if you are trying to gradually increment the values to produce animation.